# Get table column by data attribute of element

Tags: javascript

I have a table and in it I have div element with data attribute that contains ID.

```
 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ....
            <th class="selected">
               <div data-id="161380">
                  Condiments
               </div>
            </th>
            ...
        </tr>
      </thead>
   </table>
```

I need to remove class from the column  if I am given ID that matches the one in data attr.  If it were in jQuery id simply  do something like:

```
var id = "161380";

$("[data-id]="+id).closest("th").removeClass("selected");
```

However, I need to do it in vanila JS and my skills are pretty rusted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

You have some missing quotes and brackets too

```js
const id = "161380";

document.querySelector("[data-id='"+id+"']")
  .closest("th")
    .classList
      .remove("selected");
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th class="selected">
        <div data-id="161380">
          Condiments 1
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="selected">
        <div data-id="1234">
          Condiments 2
        </div>
      </th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```